# Como utilizar un array sin que aparezca sus corchetes y comillas - Javacript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array:

```
arr = ['{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,119…3303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]}', '{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-3…80443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}', '{"name" :"2022-06","data" :[-37206,-150870,557932,…9,125193,121075,43071,83886,122242,242863,86600]}', '{"name" :"2022-07","data" :[283306,111983,128260,1…235905,345279,57132,132560,204066,177546,272639]}', '{"name" :"2022-08","data" :[235802,235413,95417,13…51033,146644,180573,167246,-290330,354458,26594]}']
```

este array necesito utilizarlo para graficarlo en la siguiente linea
Ejemplo de manera manual:

```
options_ngr_total_diario.series = [{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,119970,249000,-66259,134527,193362,99277,-19567,108284,248939,241789,224130,100789,107930,-76107,113509,104240,235695,-45184,102598,113303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]},{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-317839,208278,203713,212284,90929,142553,15752,191791,17052,51734,300895,392242,198065,163279,228416,41949,195923,-94365,11067,134544,188480,180443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}];
```

pero no funciona porque entendería que cuando lo llamo al array:

```
options_ngr_total_diario.series = arr ;
```

lo esta llevando con las comillas y sus corchetes intenté convertirlo a string pero en ese caso al llamarlo al string tampoco funciona.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es `options_ngr_total_diario.series = arr.map(item => JSON.parse(item))`, para transformar cada elemento en un objeto

Answer (score 0):

En realidad lo que tienes es un array de string. Lo único que tienes que hacer es extraerlos y concatenarlos en una variable con el formato que quieres.

Por ejemplo algo así

```
  var arr = ['{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,1193303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]}', '{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-380443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}', '{"name" :"2022-06","data" :[-37206,-150870,557932,9,125193,121075,43071,83886,122242,242863,86600]}', '{"name" :"2022-07","data" :[283306,111983,128260,1235905,345279,57132,132560,204066,177546,272639]}', '{"name" :"2022-08","data" :[235802,235413,95417,1351033,146644,180573,167246,-290330,354458,26594]}'];

  var series = 'options_ngr_total_diario.series = [';

  var primero = true
  arr.forEach( el => {
    if(!primero){
      series += ',';
    } else {
      primero = false;
    }
    series += el;
  });

  series += ']';

  console.log(series);
```

Inicializo la variable **series** con la primera parte del string de salida.

Con el forEach recorro el array y extraigo cada string y los voy concatenando en el string anterior.

La variable **primero** me dice si es el primer elemento de la lista y si no es el primero, añado una coma para separar del elemento anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene un array de `string` pero no sé si ha notado que dentro del array de número tiene tres puntos `(…)` y eso genera error al momento de parsear los datos, Si eliminando esos puntos le funciona puede usar la función `map` para volverlos objetos y así los puede manipular según necesite:

```
arr = ['{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,119…3303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]}', '{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-3…80443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}', '{"name" :"2022-06","data" :[-37206,-150870,557932,…9,125193,121075,43071,83886,122242,242863,86600]}', '{"name" :"2022-07","data" :[283306,111983,128260,1…235905,345279,57132,132560,204066,177546,272639]}', '{"name" :"2022-08","data" :[235802,235413,95417,13…51033,146644,180573,167246,-290330,354458,26594]}']

const newArr = arr.map(x => JSON.parse(x.replace("…",""))) 

console.log(newArr)

options_ngr_total_diario.series = newArr
```

Yo lo probé eliminando los "…" pero ojo que no son `...` sino algún tipo de caracteres especiales. Y por supuesto, puede evitar instanciar la variable newArr (la puse como ejemplo)

Answer (score 0):

Recorrer y construir un array auxiliar con los elementos requeridos

```js
let arr = ['{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,1193303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]}', '{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-380443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}', '{"name" :"2022-06","data" :[-37206,-150870,557932,9,125193,121075,43071,83886,122242,242863,86600]}', '{"name" :"2022-07","data" :[283306,111983,128260,1235905,345279,57132,132560,204066,177546,272639]}', '{"name" :"2022-08","data" :[235802,235413,95417,1351033,146644,180573,167246,-290330,354458,26594]}'];


   
  let auxi= arr.map((obj)=>JSON.parse(obj))
console.log(auxi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quiero suponer que los puntos suspensivos (`…`) son para resumir, evitando una cantidad de valores que no es necesaria.

Como tienes un arreglo de cadenas que representan objetos JSON, te sugiero crear una nueva variable, donde interpretes cada una para convertirla en objeto y obtener un arreglo de objetos.

Creo que el método [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) es útil para este caso:

```js
let arr = [
    '{"name" :"2022-04","data" :[152043,34566,32822,119,3303,62443,106813,198610,7471,93079,94010,61480]}',
    '{"name" :"2022-05","data" :[202902,167302,18397,-3,80443,145507,176171,-538951,110725,40155,169434]}',
    '{"name" :"2022-06","data" :[-37206,-150870,557932,9,125193,121075,43071,83886,122242,242863,86600]}',
    '{"name" :"2022-07","data" :[283306,111983,128260,1,235905,345279,57132,132560,204066,177546,272639]}',
    '{"name" :"2022-08","data" :[235802,235413,95417,13,51033,146644,180573,167246,-290330,354458,26594]}'
];

// Recorrer arreglo original, en cada iteración se recibe acumulador y elemento actual
let series = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Interpretar JSON del elemento actual e insertar en acumulador
    acc.push(JSON.parse(cur));
    // Devolver acumulador
    return acc;
}, []); // El acumulador inicia como arreglo vacío

// Ahora sí es un objeto
console.log(series);
```